# How and When the SwiftUI will recalculate the body? What's SwiftUI View's lifecircle?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Look at this demo:

```
struct ColorView:View {
    @State var changed = false
    
    init(){
        print("ColorView init")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        print("calculate ColorView's body")
       return ZStack{
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundStyle(changed ? Color.red : Color.blue)
            Button(changed.description) {
                changed.toggle()
                print("ColorView's color changed")
            }
            .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
        }
       
    }
}

struct ListView:View {
    
    init(){
        print("ListView init")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        print("calculate ListView's body")
       return ZStack{
            ScrollView {
                VStack{
                    ForEach(1..<30) { index in
                        Text("\(index)")
                            .frame(width: screenWidth, height: 50)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum Tabs{
    case list,color
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var tab = Tabs.list

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            switch tab {
            case .list:
                ListView()
            case .color:
                ColorView()
            }
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                Button("Change") {
                    print("change page")
                    tab = tab == .list ? .color : .list
                }
                .padding()
                .background {
                    Color.white
                }
            }
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some doubts for me:

1 When I switch pages, SwiftUI creates a new instance of the view, but the view's body is not always recalculated.

2 ListView and ColorView are different views with no shared state. The default view is ListView. On each tab change, ColorView's body is recalculated, but ListView's is not. When I change the @State property changed in ColorView, ListView's body gets recalculated on every tab change, but ColorView's does not.

3 Despite being different instances or undergoing body recalculation, ColorView always displays the correct color based on the changed property. However, ListView resets the scroll position of ScrollView whenever its body is recalculated.

Here is the result of my run in terminal:

```
-change page
-ColorView init
-calculate ColorView's body
-change page
-ListView init
-change page
-ColorView init
-calculate ColorView's body
-change page
-ListView init
-change page
-ColorView init
-calculate ColorView's body
-ColorView's color changed   #tap the button in ColorView
-calculate ColorView's body
-change page
-ListView init
-calculate ListView's body   #the offset of ScrollView is reset
-change page
-ColorView init
-change page
-ListView init
-calculate ListView's body

#ColorView always have the correct color of all the case
```

Comment: Some good info about View updates in this article https://mobileappcircular.com/how-to-avoid-repeating-swiftui-view-updates-dcf0a65d3758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following by [Apple Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022). This is what they call `dependency graph`

> The secret of the graph is that if the dependency changes, only those views will be invalidated. SwiftUI will call each view's body, producing a new body value for each view. SwiftUI will instantiate the values of each invalidated view's body. A view's value is short-lived. But the view itself has a longer lifetime.

So each view in SwiftUI will have an identity, which is involved in the `graph`. And when the `graph` makes a decision to generate a new body, it will find the right view's identity. Then update only the view which requires a new body.

Comment: I knew that, but look at the code and result,  I can't understand when I changed the page, they have different state, and I change the property in ColorView, ListView will change its behavior on each tab change

Comment: I don't know why you're facing this problem. I've tried to run on iOS 16.2. The print log was as expected. The tab content is always generated again after swapping between list and color because there is nothing to hold it. The color in ColorView will reset to false, and the ListView content offset will also reset to 0. Maybe you want to clean & build again.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just try it on simulator or real device, it works as expected. The problem just on the Preview canvas in Xcode. Seems like the preview is not reliable :(. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help.